# Oracle order or rank by String keywords

Tags: sql, oracle

In our oracle 12c database, I have a table address

Schema:

```
Integer personId as PK
String  source (what the source data from) 
String  address1
String  address2 
String  post code 
etc...
```

example of the rows:

```
p1, news paper(Primary), add1, add2, ....
p1, google    (Primary), add1, add2, ....
p1, phone     (Secondary), add1, add2, ....
p2  new paper (Primary), add1, add2......
p3  phone (Secondary), add1, add2.....
```

**problem**: 
I need each person have a unique address. although most person would have only 1 address, but there are cases that one person end up with 2 or more address

current solution:

```
 select * from (
  select person_id, source,row_number() over(partition by person_id order by source) rn from address
  )a
  where a.rn = 1
```

the query order the duplicates by the alphabetical order of the source, and removed 1 of the duplicate

however I can't just simply order it by the alphabetical order, because any source contains (Primary) takes precedence over any other sources, also each person is not guaranteed to have just 1 Primary address, it might have two Secondary address or 2 Primary address, but in most cases it would have a Primary and a Secondary

Comment: You need to make up some business rules and test them for validity. It doesn't look like you've got enough information to arrive at some definitive business rules without validation against some outside data set. Source: I build systems that do this.

Comment: @ben you based in Bristol?

Comment: No, I'm not....

Comment: @ben alright...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue the way you started. So far you only rank (i.e. order) by source. You want another ranking (i.e. order)? Then apply it. E.g.:

```
select * 
from
(
  select 
    person_id, 
    source,
    row_number() over(
      partition by person_id
      order by case when source like '%(Primary)%' then 1 else 2 end, source) as rn
  from address
) a
where a.rn = 1;
```

Comment: I knew I was close, I was just not sure order by could combine with case statement, thank you very much